# What are single particle quantum states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics

Can someone explain what is the meaning of single particle states? I found this on Huang's book on statistical mechanics while writing distribution functions (e.g, Bose-Einstein or Fermi-Dirac). We were dealing with states of the full system in the partition function and suddenly why did we need single particle states? I cannot understand. Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A single-particle state is the eigenstate of a single-particle hamiltonian, i.e., a hamiltonian describing a single particle, usually without interactions with other particles.

Comment: Why do single-particle states appear in distribution functions? The partition function contains energy levels of the full system.

Comment: If you talk about distribution functions, like the Fermi-Dirac distribution, or the Bose-Einstein distribution function, the reason is that they describe non-interacting systems, where the total system energy is simply the sum of single-particle energies of occupied states.

Comment: @ flaudemus, "describe non-interacting systems..."  System or subsystems? Maybe more clear be:   Describe systems that can be represented as a set of non-interacting subsystems, and then the partition function of a system is the product of the partition functions of subsystems?

Comment: @AlekseyDruggist: to be more precise: systems of non-interacting fermions or bosons.

Answer (score -3):

A single particle state is defined as that which belongs to a vector space associated with an irreducible representation of the Poincare algebra and other internal symmetries. Please refer to The Quantum Theory of Fields, Volume 1, Chapter 2 by Steven Weinberg.

Comment: Maybe you can clarify how and why the QFT definition applies in this case.

Comment: The question doesn't give enough information on what is the calculation being referred to. Weinberg's definition gives a good notion of how to interpret bound states as single particle states which seemed relevant to me here. I don't think this definition is restricted to QFT or should be termed "QFT definition". It is the clearest definition I know of single particle states. The other upvoted answer here is in fact circular.